# What force is needed to turn the Earth Pole-over Pole. Eg. UK now on Equator?

Tags: earth, rotation

Specifically, if someone could specify the Joules energy required to force the Earth to slowly rotate the poles end-to-end by say 1 degrees rotation, and by 5 degrees.
To be clear I mean to literally rotate the Earth (both poles in opposite directions), say Singapore will therefore be below the Equator.

I am writing three odd stories and this is a fact I would like to be sure of, instead of trying to work it out with formulas.

Much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not the energy that you need, it's the angular momentum. What are you transferring the angular momentum to? The Moon?

Comment: I'm just wanting to know the energy required to apply to the Earth to turn the planet's poles by a small amount. But to answer your question, the application is to apply dual angular momentum well south of the equator, each apparatus offset to take energy from the earth-moon-gravity system, and thus transfer that energy to the moon which will balance the AM equation.

Comment: You mean you are applying torque? Again, it's not a matter of energy. You don't want to change the period of a day, do you? If you don't, then there is no need to change the rotational energy of the planet. The real question is what mechanism are you going to use to apply the torque? Any ideas, yet?

Comment: Strictly speaking u can calculate it, by applying a torque and integrating the torque across the angular displacement,you would require the inertia tensor and the angular acceleration of the object so it's dependent on the angular acceleration

Comment: Thanks guys. Putting my question on HOLD, has done me in. This is 6/6 questions in last few years that were canned here. I'm baffled. Aren't questions allowed? Learning? Curiosity. You need a new supreme commander overlord. I'll go elsewhere. No offense to you, your answers are appreciated.

Comment: @Achbarr Some people believe physics.stackexchange.com suffers from overly aggressive moderation. You might try asking on another stack, but also do make some effort to show what work you've already put in.